# Good source of information about AMOVA

Tags: references, genetics, biostatistics

I'm looking for a good source of information about Analysis of Molecular Variance (AMOVA), a kind of statistical analysis used in population genetics. Especially how are the $\phi$-statistics calculated and what is the difference compare to F-statistics (fixation index) in measuring the level of differentiation among diffrent population divisions.

Answer (score 3):

I know you didn't ask for an implementation of it, but the fact that a free one exists in package [ade4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ade4/index.html) for R must be helpful.  The help file references

Excoffier, L., Smouse, P.E. and Quattro, J.M. (1992) "Analysis of molecular variance inferred from metric distances among DNA haplotypes: application to human mitochondrial DNA restriction data." *Genetics*, 131, 479–491.

Which is also cited by Wikipedia and I would guess (not my area) is the definitive reference.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice tutorial on [Analysis of Molecular Variance](http://userwww.sfsu.edu/~efc/classes/biol710/amova/amova.htm), by Peter Werner, which discusses the use of $F$- or $\phi$-statistics. You may also want to take a closer look at the following paper, for a more complete overview:

> Meirmans PG. Using the AMOVA framework to estimate a standardized
>   genetic differentiation measure. *Evolution*. 2006
>   **60(11)**:2399-402.

To add to Peter's response, there's a nice "add-on" to `ade4` for genetic data: [adegenet](http://adegenet.r-forge.r-project.org/), and AMOVA is also available in the [pegas](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pegas/index.html) R package.

Answer (score 2):

I was interested in the same problem and [here](http://www.epscor.hawaii.edu/sites/web41.its.hawaii.edu.www.epscor.hawaii.edu/files/er_book/2012/05/Birdetal_Detecting_Measuring.pdf) is link for the best sourse I found then. There is also nice example, what is missing in many other sources about AMOVA.